# problem with intersect operation in a sql query

Tags: sql, intersection

I wrote the following query, I think it's correct but I have a "missing operator" error.

```
SELECT * FROM results,Types WHERE results.a=Types.b  
INTERSECT  SELECT * FROM results,Types WHERE results.c=Types.b
```

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What DB engine and version please? I can't reproduce on SQL Server 2005 SP3

Comment: I'm pretty sure MSAccess doesn't support INTERSECT. You will need to join on all the columns. Can you indicate the column list returned by `*` and which of the columns are allowed to be NULL?

Comment: Please share more details such that others can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What database are you using? Are you sure that `intersect` is supported? I tried your query on Oracle (changing the table names to something corresponding to my DB) and it worked ok.

EDIT:
Since you confirmed you are using MS-Access, then it's clear that INTERSECT is the problem since it's not supported with MS-Access: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/archive/index.php/t-86531.html

EDIT2:
This is untested, but the basic idea is that you need to find all rows in your first query that exist in your second query. To do that, you will have to compare every column between the 2 queries for a match, as all the columns must match for it to be an "intersected" row.

There may be some syntax issues, but hopefully this gets you started.

```
SELECT r.col1
     , t.col1
     /* list all other columns here */
  FROM results r
     , types t
 WHERE r.a = t.b
 AND EXISTS (
     SELECT *
       FROM results r2
          , types   t2
      WHERE r2.c = t2.b
        AND NZ(r.col1,0) = NZ(r2.col1,0)
        AND NZ(t.col1,0) = NZ(t2.col1,0)
        /* list other columns here, they all need to match so intersection will work */
 )
```

Comment: I use MSAccess. I am not sure, I will check now.

Comment: you're right. it does not support INTERSECTION. So, what should I do if I want to intersect them?

Comment: @Shadi - Yes, it's unfortunate that intersection isn't available. It means you'll have to do things the hard way, see EDIT2 above. I haven't tested it, but I think the idea should hopefully work.

Comment: `INTERSECT` treats NULLs as equal for comparison purposes so to reproduce that there would need to be a load of IFNULLs or whatever the Access syntax is.

Comment: @Martin Smith - Thank you for your comment. I updated my answer to reflect this. Seems NZ is the equivalent of IFNULL in ACCESS.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the non-ANSI join is confusing matters

```
SELECT * FROM results R JOIN Types T ON R.a = T.b  
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM results R JOIN Types T ON R.c = T.b
```

Comment: Even if they aren't confusing matters, implicit joins are a very poor technique and they should be replaced. Of course the query should not be using select * either!

Comment: @HLGEM: one thing at a time :-)

Comment: It did not work with JOIN as well. SELECT queries work separately, but not together.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest testing each of the `SELECT` statements separately. Make sure they work by themselves. Then do the `INTERSECT`.

If you are working with SQL Server, for example, that is not the correct way to refer to two tables. You would need to add a `JOIN` clause (with an `ON` specifying the columns to `JOIN`).

Even if it isn't SQL Server, you need to make sure that the queries each work on their own.

Edit: Someone else has asked here about [How can I implement SQL INTERSECT and MINUS operations in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access). I see a difference of opinion there, so be sure to test your results to make sure you're getting what you want.

Comment: the "SELECT"s work well separately, but they don't work together even with "JOIN".

Answer (score 0):

Use INTERSECT statement only if u want to find common line produce by the individual querys.
You're statement:

"  SELECT * FROM results,Types WHERE results.a=Types.b
   INTERSECT  SELECT * FROM results,Types WHERE results.c=Types.b   "

don't match the criteria needed for the joint to work."WHERE" clause is creating the problem.

If results.a<>results.c :than u...have nothing to INTERSECT.