# Implementing INTERSECT (INNER JOIN) in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, intersect

I've been looking at how to convert what I have as UNION to INTERSECT, but there is no INTERSECT keyword in MS Access.

I've been very confused as to how the following code would look like using inner join if I wanted the intersection of these two select statements instead of the Union of them.

I know I can achieve what I want if I SELECT DISTINCT and then use inner join but the ON keyword really confuses me.

I just started a week ago with SQL so if you see anything else wrong with the code I'll accept all constructive criticism :)

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Catt].[Name]
FROM [Catt]
WHERE ((([Catt].[Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![Main]![SrchText] & "*") 
AND [forms]![Main]!   [SrchText] IS NOT Null AND [forms]![Main]![SrchText]<>''  )

UNION

SELECT [Catt].[Name]
FROM [Catt]
WHERE  ((([Catt].[Category]) Like [forms]![Main]![Combo7].Value) AND (([forms]![Main]!    [SrchText] IS Null) OR ([forms]![Main]![SrchText]=''))))  AS Query
ORDER BY [Catt].[Name];
```

Thank you.

Comment: u cant union or intersect if you dont have same number of columns in view

Comment: Oh, so because I am using [Name] and [Category] in the seconds select, an intersect will not work? The thing is that Union has been working for me so far, just wanted to change to intersection.

Comment: Yes I got it. what I meant is you cant union Select * and Select catt.name. I'll give a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement SQL INTERSECT and MINUS operations in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this so definitely you will have a lot of MS Access specific changes to be made. But I ask you not to obfuscate query by unnecessarily quoting each identifier in square blocks:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT title
FROM       (  
            SELECT [Catt].[Name] as title
            FROM   [Catt]
            WHERE  ([Catt].[Name] Like "*" & [forms]![Main]![SrchText] & "*") AND 
                    [forms]![Main]![SrchText] IS NOT Null AND 
                    [forms]![Main]![SrchText] <>''
           ) AS view1

INNER JOIN 

           (   
            SELECT   [Catt].[Name]
            FROM     [Catt]
            WHERE    [Catt].[Category] Like [forms]![Main]![Combo7].Value AND 
                     ([forms]![Main]![SrchText] IS Null OR 
                      [forms]![Main]![SrchText]='')
           ) AS view2 ON view1.title = view2.Name

ORDER BY   view1.title
```

But basically something like this does the trick..

Edited as Gordon pointed out

Comment: Using `ORDER BY` within the subquery (view2) seems wrong to me.  If you want `ORDER BY`, do it outside the subqueries.

Comment: @HansUp I guess its fine now?

Comment: Better.  Thanks for that formatting ... makes it much easier to read.  I'll add some changes.  Roll back my changes if you disagree.

Comment: @HansUp sure, and I can always make the query concise and faster by avoiding trivial selects, but I felt I would leave it as such so that the OP understands how INTERSECT is done btw two queries. Putting ORDER BY inside the subquery is one such optimization I left out intentionally to make the query clearer for OP

Comment: @HansUp do I need the first `SELECT *` from and then another inner query? Cant I directly write: `SELECT [Catt].[Name]
            FROM   [Catt]
            WHERE  ........ AS view1` ?

Comment: You must SELECT something in each subquery.  And the parent query, which uses the subqueries as its data sources, must also SELECT something.  Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @HansUp what I meant is: Do we need to write this: `SELECT     * 
FROM       (  
            SELECT [Catt].[Name]
            FROM   [Catt]
            WHERE  .......
           ) AS view1`.

Or is it enough if we write : `SELECT [Catt].[Name]
            FROM   [Catt]
            WHERE  .......... AS view1`? Ok lemme test it

Comment: @nawfal oh wow, thank you very much! I will try this out and come back with the results.

Comment: Can you SELECT [Catt].[Name]  FROM either view1 or view2?  FROM [Catt] would not be available to the query outside the sub queries.