# Minus Query in MsAccess

Tags: database, ms-access

What is the correct syntax for Minus Query in MS ACCESS

> I want to compare entire result set of 2 queries not just only key
> column comparisons

For Eg:

> hello table data: id,name,address
>
> hello1 table data:new_id,new_name,new_address

I want to find out who are all the customers with changed data in any column.

I had given following query .it failed

```
select h.* from hello h
minus
select h1.* from hello1 h1
```

Please let me know correct query

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement SQL INTERSECT and MINUS operations in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is NOT IN. There is no such thing as a minus query in MS Access.

```
select h.* from hello h
WHERE uniqueid NOT IN
(select uniqueid from hello1 h1)
```

For a purely sql solution, you need, say:

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN NewTable n
ON t.ID = n.ID
WHERE t.Field1 & "" <> n.Field1 & ""
   OR t.Field2 & "" <> n.Field2 & ""
```

However, it is easier using VBA.

Comment: I may have dynamic key columns.. I am using this in macro. I need to compare results of 2 queries not just only key ids

Comment: Your question is quite vague in that it does not contain any sample data or required result. There is no minus query in MS Access and without additional information, it is not possible to do more than suggest possibilities. Another possibility is a Left Join.

Comment: I have given an example in my question description. Please see it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an id that you can use to match the tables? It is best to supply much more realistic data sets, or too much discussion is required, which is discouraged by SO.

Comment: but this wont identify when there is new id value in any table. this query will select only matching columns i need the result for unmatched records as well.

Comment: The above query uses a LEFT JOIN, that is all records from Table are included and any matched rows from NewTable. Appending a zero length string on both sides means that fields in Table that do not have a match in NewTable will be included, even if there is no matching record in NewTable. You can reverse the join to get fields in NewTable that are not matched in Table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13272/discussion-between-logan-and-remou)