# Subtracting Lists from Queries in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have five fields in a Master Query named Suche. Lets consider the names of the fields for an easy demonstration as A,B,C,D,E. The Suche Query looks something like this

```
A         B           C           D            E
1         a           b                        d
2         m           n           o            
3         t           z   
4         r           m           d            b
5         q           f           j
```

I have extracted two queries from the Suche Query. The First Query is called DUN and it extracts the following from Suche Query

```
A         B           C           D            E
1         a           b                        d
```

and the 2nd Query is called HOL and it extracts the following from Suche Query.

```
A         B           C           D            E
3         t           z   
4         r           m           d            b
```

Now I am looking to Build a Third Query where I want to find the remaining unextracted records from the Suche Query. I have tried to achieve it something like this

```
SELECT (Suche.A-DUN.A-HOL.A) AS FINAL FROM Suche,DUN,HOL;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `not in` or `not exists`.  Assuming that column `A` is unique, you can do:

```
select s.*
from (<Suche>) as s
where s.A not in (select d.a from (<DUN>) as d) and
      s.A not in (select h2.a from (<HOL>) as h2);
```

Comment: My Bad! Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood, you could use the MINUS operator like this:

CREATE TABLE fin AS
  (SELECT * FROM suche
MINUS
  SELECT * FROM dun
MINUS
  SELECT * FROM hol);

If you do not need create the table, ignores the CREATE TABLE and use the subquery directly.

Comment: SQL is a generic tab, the specific version asked for is MS Access.

Comment: MS Access does not support the MINUS operator. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282433/minus-query-in-msaccess and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access. The alternative is to use  NOT IN or NOT EXISTS as Gordon Linoff has suggested.