# How can I compare sequences using SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This may be a little complicated, but I'm not sure how to explain it any more simply.

I have two tables of sequences:

t1:

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| state | sequence | gie   | match |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| a     |        1 | fna   |       |
| c     |        2 | fna   |       |
| b     |        3 | fna   |       |
| d     |        1 | dmc   |       |
| c     |        2 | dmc   |       |
| c     |        3 | dmc   |       |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
```

t2:

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| state | sequence | gie   | match |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| a     |        1 | fna   |       |
| d     |        2 | fna   |       |
| c     |        3 | fna   |       |
| b     |        4 | fna   |       |
| d     |        1 | dmc   |       |
| c     |        2 | dmc   |       |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
```

For each sequence of a given `group`, I want to find all the records from `t2` that don't fit in a sequence in `t1`, and vice versa.  In `t1`, the non-matched record is GIE `dmc`, sequence `3`; in `t2`, the non-matched record is GIE `fna`, sequence `2`.

I haven't been able to figure out how to use SQL to find the non-matches, because it's not clear what I should be joining on.  I tried it with VBA as follows:

```
'assumes both recordsets are ordered by GIE,sequence
Sub findNonMatch(rs_base As DAO.Recordset, rs_compare As DAO.Recordset)

rs_base.MoveFirst
rs_compare.MoveFirst

While Not rs_base.EOF
    If rs_compare.EOF Then
        updateRS rs_base, False
    'separated into different if-clauses because checking rs_compare!GIE will throw error if rs_compare.eof
    Else
        If rs_compare!gie < rs_base!gie Then
        While rs_compare!gie < rs_base!gie
            rs_compare.MoveNext
        Wend
        End If

        While (rs_compare!gie = rs_base!gie And rs_compare!state <> rs_base!state And (Not rs_compare.EOF))
            rs_compare.MoveNext
        Wend
        If (rs_compare!state = rs_base!state And rs_compare!gie = rs_base!gie) Then
            updateRS rs_base, True
            rs_compare.MoveNext
        End If
    End If
    rs_base.MoveNext

Wend

End Sub

Sub updateRS(rs As DAO.Recordset, status As Boolean)
rs.Edit
rs!Match = status
rs.update
End Sub
```

This works if the sequence in `rs_compare` has an extra value that's not in `rs_base`, but if `rs_compare` is missing a value that's in `rs_base`, the method doesn't work properly, because the function will try to find that value and go to the end of the `rs_compare` sequence, meaning that any `rs_base` values thereafter will not be found (since the `rs_compare` cursor has now gone past all of the records in that sequence).

Is there an easier way to find these sequence discrepancies?  Maybe some SQL approach I haven't thought of, especially because this algorithm won't scale well for larger data sets?

Comment: Hi, you wrote: "in t2, the non-matched record is GIE fna, sequence 2."  Did you mean sequence 4?

Comment: @VBlades, no, it's sequence 2; the value there is "d", and there is no "d" following the "a" in table `t1` sequence 1.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Will think about it more.  Interesting problem.

Comment: Hey I have a solution, I think (whether it is a good one, not sure, lol), but would like to test with another set of data.  Would it be possible to provide another set of mock data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this way to implement minus in ms access [How can I implement SQL INTERSECT and MINUS operations in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access).

What you will do is left outer join t1 to t2 on sequence, state, and GIE and select all rows where t2.id is null.

Then you can union that query with a second query that left outer join t2 to t1 on sequence, state, and GIE and select all rows where t1.id is null.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, because if `t2` has one extra record in the middle of a sequence, that will throw off all the `t2.sequence` from that point on and I won't be able to match them against the corresponding `t1.sequence`.

Comment: Then how can we tell that two sequences are the same?

Comment: I'm not just trying to match the sequences in entirety.  I think that user3260813's answer correctly characterizes this as a longest common substring problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is Longest Common Substring problem for comparing of two strings.

Check the code in VBA http://thydzik.com/longest-common-subsequence-implemented-in-vba-visual-basic-for-applications/

You should get string1 and string2 somehow from Access, and use the functions in a link.
So for your example

```
  String1 = acb
  String2 = adcb
```

Check the example function in a link, to understand how to use it.  The output of a ‘getDiff‘ function will be

```
 =+==
```

So the difference is in 2 place. + means insert 'd' in string 1 to make strings equal.

Answer (score 1):

I mocked some test data up on my own and it seemed to be functioning as expected, so thought I would post.  I wanted to have the SQL do the heavy lifting, and it does, but there is still a bit of code to run.  I have put the accdb (Access 2007) file here if you just care to try it out: http://www.sendspace.com/file/eqm5vh.  If you do, just enter your data into t1 and t2, then open Module1 and run RunSequences; the sub should take care of the rest.

My code is not as concise as yours, sigil, and requires more helper objects.  That being said, it could possibly scale better than a purely cursor-based solution as it only has to run through one row (more or less, depending on how many duplicates, if any, across tables) for each item in each table.  My idea was to be able to sequence each table on a row-by-row basis (like ROW_NUMBER in SQL Server) so I could have a absolute position for comparison.  I did this by inserting all the data from both tables into a temp table with an AutoNumber field, then doing the old DCount trick to get row ids.  The rest is based off this dataset.  Instead of explaining to death, I will just let you try it out and see if it works, but I will post my code below in case anyone wants to review.

**Table:**

[image: tblTemp]

**Queries:**

qryT1T2_Ordered_INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tblTemp
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "t1" AS SourceTable, t1.State, t1.Sequence, t1.GIE, t1.Match
FROM t1

UNION ALL

SELECT "t2" AS SourceTable, t2.State, t2.Sequence, t2.GIE, t2.Match
FROM t2)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
ORDER BY SourceTable, GIE DESC , Sequence;
```

qryT1_Sequenced:

```
SELECT DCount("*","tblTemp","[SourceTable] = 't1' AND [ID] <= " & [ID]) AS SequenceID, tblTemp.ID, tblTemp.State, tblTemp.Sequence, tblTemp.GIE, tblTemp.Match, [State] & "_" & [GIE] AS JoinValue
FROM tblTemp
WHERE tblTemp.SourceTable="t1";
```

qryT1_Compare:

```
SELECT qryT1_Sequenced.SequenceID AS MySequenceID, qryT2_Sequenced.SequenceID AS OtherSequenceID, qryT1_Sequenced.ID AS MyID, qryT2_Sequenced.ID AS OtherID, qryT2_Sequenced.JoinValue
FROM qryT1_Sequenced LEFT JOIN qryT2_Sequenced ON qryT1_Sequenced.JoinValue = qryT2_Sequenced.JoinValue
ORDER BY qryT1_Sequenced.SequenceID, qryT2_Sequenced.ID;
```

qryT2_Sequenced:

```
SELECT DCount("*","tblTemp","[SourceTable] = 't2' AND [ID] <= " & [ID]) AS SequenceID, tblTemp.ID, tblTemp.State, tblTemp.Sequence, tblTemp.GIE, tblTemp.Match, [State] & "_" & [GIE] AS JoinValue
FROM tblTemp
WHERE tblTemp.SourceTable="t2";
```

qryT2_Compare:

```
SELECT qryT2_Sequenced.SequenceID AS MySequenceID, qryT1_Sequenced.SequenceID AS OtherSequenceID, qryT2_Sequenced.ID AS MyID, qryT1_Sequenced.ID AS OtherID, qryT2_Sequenced.JoinValue
FROM qryT2_Sequenced LEFT JOIN qryT1_Sequenced ON qryT2_Sequenced.JoinValue=qryT1_Sequenced.JoinValue
ORDER BY qryT2_Sequenced.SequenceID, qryT1_Sequenced.ID;
```

qryT1T2_Compared_FINAL:

```
SELECT tblTemp.SourceTable, tblTemp.State, tblTemp.Sequence, tblTemp.GIE, tblTemp.Match
FROM tblTemp
WHERE tblTemp.Match="No"
ORDER BY tblTemp.SourceTable, tblTemp.GIE DESC , tblTemp.Sequence;
```

**Module:**

```
Public Sub RunSequences()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    'Do our setup:
    '1. Clear our temp table.
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [tblTemp]"

    '2. Insert data from t1 and t2 into temp table.
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryT1T2_Ordered_INSERT"

    '3. Now process the sequence.
    ReportSequences "qryT1_Compare"
    ReportSequences "qryT2_Compare"

    '4. Open non-matched report.
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryT1T2_Compared_FINAL"

ExitMe:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitMe
End Sub

'----

Public Sub ReportSequences(strSourceQuery As String)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim intLastOtherSequenceID As Integer
    Dim dicMasterSequenceIDs As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dicComparedSequenceIDs As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim strSQL_UpdateYes As String
    Dim strSQL_UpdateNo As String

    'Running all my updates inline, but you can break this out.
    strSQL_UpdateYes = "UPDATE [tblTemp] SET [Match] = 'Yes' WHERE [ID] = @ID"
    strSQL_UpdateNo = "UPDATE [tblTemp] SET [Match] = 'No' WHERE [ID] = @ID"

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSourceQuery, dbOpenDynaset)

    With rst
        Do Until .EOF
            'Need this to keep track of Master Sequence IDs (MyID) we've processed
            'successfully.
            'If there is more than one match for MyID, we want only to take the first
            'match that fulfills the condition of being next in the sequence,
            'not jump ahead.
            If dicMasterSequenceIDs.Exists(.Fields("MyID").Value) = True Then
                If dicMasterSequenceIDs(.Fields("MyID").Value) = "Done" Then
                    GoTo MoveNext
                End If
            Else
                dicMasterSequenceIDs.Add .Fields("MyID").Value, ""
            End If

            Select Case IsNull(.Fields("OtherID"))
                Case True
                    'If OtherID is null, it means no match in other table, so Match is
                    'automatically no.
                    db.Execute Replace(strSQL_UpdateNo, "@ID", .Fields("MyID"))
                Case False
                    'Check to see if current OtherSequenceID is greater than the old
                    'one...
                    '(If it is, it is in sequence).
                    If intLastOtherSequenceID < CInt(.Fields("OtherSequenceID")) Then
                        'Use the dictionary to keep track of distinct OtherSequenceIDs we've already added.
                        If dicComparedSequenceIDs.Exists(.Fields("OtherSequenceID").Value) = False Then
                            dicComparedSequenceIDs.Add .Fields("OtherSequenceID").Value, ""
                            db.Execute Replace(strSQL_UpdateYes, "@ID", .Fields("MyID"))
                            dicMasterSequenceIDs(.Fields("MyID").Value) = "Done"
                        'If it's a dupe, means the sequence is broken.
                        Else
                            db.Execute Replace(strSQL_UpdateNo, "@ID", .Fields("MyID"))
                        End If
                    Else
                        'If the old one is equal or greater, means sequence is broken.
                        db.Execute Replace(strSQL_UpdateNo, "@ID", .Fields("MyID"))
                    End If

                    intLastOtherSequenceID = .Fields("OtherSequenceID")
            End Select

MoveNext:
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

ExitMe:
    Set dicComparedSequenceIDs = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitMe

End Sub
```

Anyway, hope it works for you.  If not, hope it can give you some more ideas.

**EDIT:** Realized there was an issue with the logic in sub ReportSequences.  In the case we got several matches in the other sequence, we want to take only the one both earliest in the sequence and which fits the criteria.  Have added that in.  New accdb here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/hcdxvp