# SQL Junction Table Help - Filtering Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a question whose answer may be all too obvious but I seem to be missing it.

I have two tables with a many to many relationship (table1 and table2) and in between a junction table (table1_table2.) I can query this junction table to give me data based on a parameter, using say

```
`SELECT * 
FROM Table1_table2 
WHERE fk_table2 = x;`
```

But, because inevitably I have some records in table1 that have multiple possible values from table2, querying the complete opposite returns some records with the foreign key of table1 without the value I've requested be left out for fk_table2. That is to say, in this table (I apologize for the crude depiction)...

```
fk_table1 |fk_table2
1         | 4
1         | 8
2         | 8
3         | 8
```

... this query...

```
`SELECT *
FROM table1_table2
WHERE fk_table <> 8;`
```

..would return `fk_table1 = 1` and its related value in table2.

So, here's my question:

What is the best way to approach the query that, if the filtering condition is met in fk_table2, all other records with the related fk_table1 are not shown?

If you've followed, essentially the query to avoid `fk_table2 = 8` should return nothing because `fk_table1 = 1` has already been accounted for.

Any ideas?

Comment: @sstan I'm currently using MS Access, though I thought the question was sufficiently universal to tag multiple DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NOT IN` with a subquery should work:

```
select *
  from Table1_table2
 where fk_table1 not in (select fk_table1
                           from Table1_table2
                          where fk_table2 = 8)
```

Answer (score -1):

In other DBMSs, you could use EXCEPT or MINUS, but MS Access does not offer this operator. See this link for the workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access