# syntax error in from clause in access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am running a simple query . I want to get the records found in both of  the tables however I get a syntax error. (syntax error in FROM clause) I run this query in my sql server 2008 and it runs smoothly but if I do this in my access db I get this syntax error

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Billing0923
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Billing916

Comment: [How can I implement SQL INTERSECT and MINUS operations in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

Again someone stuck with Access ... But don't despair, Hive has the same problem, and they have some User Defined Functions in GitHub to work around it.

For the two set operations MINUS/EXCEPT or, indeed, INTERSECT, you will have to resort to a SELECT DISTINCT a.* of one table AS a INNER JOIN-ed with the other table AS b, with all columns of the two tables in the ON clause. Ugly, I know ...

```
CREATE TABLE work ( 
  division         INT
, fips_county_code VARCHAR(3)
, last             VARCHAR(10)
, suffix           VARCHAR(3)
, first            VARCHAR(6)
, title            VARCHAR(16) 
, birthdate        DATE
);

INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Dent'      ,'','Arthur','Earthling'       ,'1957-08-02');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Prefect'   ,'','Ford'  ,'HH Guide Scout'  ,'1925-04-01');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'N/A','Beeblebrox','','Zaphod','Galaxy President','1857-09-13');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'McMillan'  ,'','Tricia','Astrophysicist'  ,'1959-09-29');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Dent'      ,'','Arthur','Earthling'       ,'1957-08-02');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'McMillan'  ,'','Tricia','Astrophysicist'  ,'1959-09-29');

CREATE TABLE work_2 ( 
  division         INT
, fips_county_code VARCHAR(3)
, last             VARCHAR(10)
, suffix           VARCHAR(3)
, first            VARCHAR(6)
, title            VARCHAR(16) 
, birthdate        DATE
);
INSERT INTO work_2 VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Dent'      ,'','Arthur','Earthling'          ,'1957-08-02');
INSERT INTO work_2 VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Prefect'   ,'','Ford'  ,'HH Guide Scout'     ,'1925-04-01');
INSERT INTO work_2 VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Prosser'   ,'','Edwin' ,'Bulldozer Team Head','1957-08-02');
INSERT INTO work_2 VALUES(1,'N/A','Halfrunt'  ,'','Gag'   ,'Musician'           ,'1925-04-01');

SELECT DISTINCT
  work.*
FROM work AS work
INNER JOIN work_2 AS cmp
   ON work.division         = cmp.division
  AND work.fips_county_code = cmp.fips_county_code
  AND work.last             = cmp.last
  AND work.suffix           = cmp.suffix
  AND work.first            = cmp.first
  AND work.title            = cmp.title
  AND work.birthdate        = cmp.birthdate
;

division|fips_county_code|last   |suffix|first |title         |birthdate
       1|UK              |Dent   |      |Arthur|Earthling     |1957-08-02 00:00:00
       1|UK              |Prefect|      |Ford  |HH Guide Scout|1925-04-01 00:00:00
```

Happy Playing

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM Billing0923
UNION
SELECT * FROM Billing916
```

Assuming your two tables have exactly the same fields. Otherwise list the fields  they have common instead of using `*`